# Vector dot products

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, vectors

> Consider two vectors $\vec{a\:}$, $\vec{b\:}$ with $|\vec{a\:}| = 2,
> > |\vec{b\:}| = 1$, and an angle between them of $60^\circ$ . Find the scalar
>   product$$\left(\vec{a\:}+\vec{b\:}\right)\cdot \left(\vec{a\:}-\vec{b\:}\right)$$

So I know that $\left(\vec{a\:}+\vec{b\:}\right)\cdot \left(\vec{a\:}-\vec{b\:}\right)= \left|\vec{a\:}\right|^2-\left|\vec{b\:}\right|^2$

But in the solution it says that it is equal to  $$\left|\vec{a\:}\right|^2-\left|\vec{a\:}\right|\left|\vec{b\:}\right|cos\:60-2\left|\vec{b\:}\right|^2$$

Why though?

edit: Here are the pics
[image: Question]

[image: Solution]

Comment: Your answer is correct

Comment: Are you sure it's not a typo? The bottom line there is equal to $ ( \textbf{a} - 2 \textbf{b} ) \cdot ( \textbf{a} + \textbf{b} )$.

Comment: No it is correct, the professor confirmed it, but I missed the explanation of why it is like this so I was hoping to get some answers here. I will post a screenshot of it.

Comment: @Naochi : Your large quotation has "$(\vec{a}+\vec{b}) \cdot (\vec{a} - \vec{b})$".  Your pic has $(\vec{a}+\vec{b}) \cdot (\vec{a} - 2\vec{b})$".  Which one do you want to talk about?

Comment: When you say "So I know that ...", are you thinking this is the difference of two squares factorization?

Answer (score 0):

the expression is given 
$$(\vec a + \vec b).(\vec a - \vec b)=\vec a.\vec a-\vec a.\vec b+\vec b.\vec a-\vec b.\vec b$$
$$=|\vec a|.|\vec a|\cos 0^o-|\vec a|.|\vec b|\cos 60^o+|\vec a|.|\vec b|\cos 60^o-|\vec b|.|\vec b|\cos 0^o$$
$$=|\vec a|.|\vec a|-|\vec b|.|\vec b|$$
$$=|\vec a|^2-|\vec b|^2$$

Comment: sorry I meant to say their magnitude but had written in their vector notation.Now it is fixed.thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

Note that you ask a question about
$$
(a+b) (a-b) 
$$
but the question in the book is about
$$
(a+b) (a-2b)
$$
I think you missed the factor of $2$.